# Shield.io badge text searchable on git wiki

Tags: git, github, wiki

In this [wiki page](https://github.com/vivirbr/wiki_test_repo/wiki/testing-badge) we can see two words and one shield.io badge. Unfortunately I was able to search using the standard git search tool only the text content as copied [here](https://github.com/vivirbr/wiki_test_repo/search?q=hello&type=Wikis). Does anyone know how to search based on the text inside the badge (SEARCHABLE)? When I tried to search for the page using the badge context text (SEARCHABLE) I find 0 wiki pages.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The content of the badge is dynamic and comes from a different site. I don't believe search indexer sees it so I don't think search could find it.

Comment: probably only if we can change the search to access the alt element in the img, inside the body, but I don't know if it's possible to do that. According to git, they search in title or body.
Do you suggest something different but that attends to the same purpose? An internal tag with a searchable text? So far we are using tags as words, but this is very susceptible to typos, that's the reason why we were considering the badges

Comment: I would like to have this feature to simply search via a browser search and hit the badges. Would be great if that are SVG with real text or something.